# animate multiple images simultaneously

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have five images, and all i need is to animate them **differently** and **simultaneously** on the screen. I got different animation codes but they use sequence of images to create animation .. or they animate a single image. Please help

Thankyou so much @Rob and @Aadhira for your interest. Here is my code that moves one image linearly.. How can i animate it in a curve

```
if(isAnimate) {
    NSLog(@"+30,+15");
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"moveView" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    searchLight1.frame = CGRectMake(searchLight1.frame.origin.x+30, searchLight1.frame.origin.y + 15, searchLight1.frame.size.width, searchLight1.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    isAnimate = NO;
}
else {
    NSLog(@"-30,-15");
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"moveView" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    searchLight1.frame = CGRectMake(searchLight1.frame.origin.x-30, searchLight1.frame.origin.y  -15, searchLight1.frame.size.width, searchLight1.frame.size.height);       
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    isAnimate = YES;
}
```

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what you want to do if you want a real answer.  But reading about Core Animation or watching the WWDC videos about Core Aimation might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what kind of animation you want and what code you are having. If you post that, it would be better.

Anyhow you know how to animate a single image. Then start animating the 5 images in 5 different blocks.

Comment: Thankyou so much Rob and Aadhira for your interest. Here is my code that move one image linearly.. How can i animate it in a curve